# Page pagination issue in Drupal website

Tags: forms, search, drupal, pagination

I have an issue in drupal website ( http://www.perfectchoice.ae/properties-browse/ ) when I go to click on 2nd page number then no property comes there.

I don't have knowledge about Drupal. Looking for someone to help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page parameter is working:

http://www.perfectchoice.ae/properties-browse/?page=3

So some other is causing the problem. When you move to some page and it doesn't show anything try removing URL parameters one by one until you figure out which one is causing the problem. But in any case you will need some Drupal knowledge to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so how can I set parameters for url for this particular issue?

Comment: That page should be a view and filter form i set of exposed view filters. So, in back-end go to Structere -> Views, find the for which generates that page, edit it, check for exposed filters... Or, as I said, find someone with Drupal knowledge (not thinking of my self).

Answer (score 0):

With the very less information provided in the description, it is difficult to figure out the issue/fix.

One probable reason would be your views is not getting displayed on the URLs other than 'properties-browse'. You need to make the visibility settings of the main block to 'properties-browse*'

Good Luck!!!